# Spfx webpart - single web part with 100+ forms in it

Tags: spfx-webparts, reactjs

I am creating a spfx-ReactJS web part for O365 site.
This is actually a java to sp re-engineering. Legacy java app has 100+ pages, I am trying to put all of these into one spfx webpart and add it to a modern page.

Is this approach correct ?
Will there be any load/performance issue.

Is it possible to load each page only on demand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you'll have performance issues, but even worse, you're going to have a supremely brittle solution that will take forever to build and deploy. Think about it - if you need to make a small change to page 57 then you need to rebuild, redeploy, and retest the entire project.

Organize your web parts into a few solutions, logically grouped. Use shared services where possible and make each separate UI unit into its own web part.